# How to extract foreground from the similar background

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, background-foreground

Provided a image, its foreground and background are similar, how to extract foreground. I hope less human intervention.
I consider:

1. background subtraction need a pre-background image, but the camera may often move. So it is unreliable
2. grabCut method in OpenCV library needs to point out the ROI, it is inconvenient

Comment: identify the differences...

Comment: Please read your post again and ask yourself: can anyone give a meaningful answer to this, given that I have provided not a single bit of useful, specific information? similar in what regard? what is the measure of similarity? what identifies fore- and background? any example images you want to share?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [this repo](https://github.com/MarcoForte/closed-form-matting), which is an implementation of [Closed-Form Matting](http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/anat.levin/papers/Matting-Levin-Lischinski-Weiss-CVPR06.pdf).

Using the command line CLI, you can pass in an image with scribbles showing the foreground and background, which is easier than pixel-level segmentation. I don't know how well the algorithm will perform on your images without more information, but it's somewhere to start.